# How do I run Android Examples

Tags: android

Does anybody know how to run the Android code examples at wrox.com from the book "Professional Android 2 Application Development"?  I downloaded both the ftp and http versions but I can't seem to run the examples in Eclipse.  I can't find the .apk extensions amongst the folders to run the programs.

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-2-Application-Development.productCd-0470565527,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File` Menu in Eclipse and then click on `Import` option. Here it will open a wizard and here click on `General` and then click on `Existing projects into Workspace` and click on `Next`. Now select the option "`Select archive file:`" then it will open file browser in which you can select the zip file which you had downloaded from the site. Then it will display all the projects in your file and just click on `Finish`.

Now you have done.